# Batch script calling batch script - Control gets missed

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Team,

I have used a batch script in my local machine to execute a batch script in my remote server. For that i have tried the following commands.

```
net use X: \\Server1\Folder1 /user:uname Pwd
X:
call Test.bat
C:
net use X: /d*
```

In the above script, first three steps gets executed and creates drive "X" after that calls "Test.bat" in the remote server. After that the control gets missed and next two steps are not getting executed.
Can anyone guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: That wont run the script on the server, it will run it locally - is that what you want?

Comment: Have `Test.bat` file an `exit` command with NO `/B` switch?

Comment: Does test.bat execute another batch file without using `call`?  Place a `pause` command at the end of test.bat and see if that is being executed.  How long does test.bat take to execute?  is there a prompt that is being redirected to NUL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `start Test.bat` if you want control to return to the first script

Comment: Using `Call` is fine for a batch file.

Comment: Using Start fixed my issue. Thanks for your suggestions guys.